# Read history of chrome app in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, url

I have read lot of answers for the same, but was not able to get the perfect answer to my question.
As of now with the marshmallow API, can I read the history from Chrome app? I want to moniter the URL that the user is visiting.
Is their an API which can get me the URL's?

Comment: I don't know of any such API. Try creating a background service to go through browsing history, periodically.

Comment: That's what my question was. is there any how a way to read the history for chrome app. If there is any api well and good, but if not then how can I get the url visited?